# Nginx test, curl return different info with (1) localhost (2) public ip

Tags: nginx, web, server

I was trying to make the Nginx work on a newly pursched aliyun server.
I first run the following command on the remote server via SSH. The output is correct.

```
[root@iZuf******meinZ ~]# curl -I 127.0.0.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.25.4
Date: Fri, 16 Feb 2024 16:09:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Feb 2024 16:20:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "65cce86a-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Next, I run the following one on my laptop's terminal. The output shows "Server: nginx/1.23.1" which is not the one I installed. Also, the index.html is not the one in the server's Nginx folder. Anyone can explained this? Thanks a lot.

```
***@***~$curl -I ***.***.***.***(public IP)
HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: nginx/1.23.1
Date: Fri, 16 Feb 2024 16:12:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: PROJECT_CODE=winery01; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Sun, 17-Mar-2024 16:12:23 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: PROJECT_ENV=pro; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Sun, 17-Mar-2024 16:12:23 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Language: en
```

I have no idea what's going on. I am pretty sure the IP address is correct. I have already setup the 80 port in the server's configuration.

Comment: Hi, this question may have a better place at https://serverfault.com